# React onClick keeps triggering

Tags: triggers, onclick, reactjs

When I trigger the `onClick` even the event keeps triggering for about 1000+ times. I can't seem to figure where this is coming from. I have changed the `onClick` to an `onMouseover` to see if it keeps triggering but then the event only triggers once.

I'm using : `react 0.13.3`

Any idea's?

```js
var React = require('react');
var AppActions = require('../../actions/app-actions.js');


var FileAmount = React.createClass({
 getInitialState: function() {
  return {
   amount : this.props.amount,
   config : this.props.config
  };
 },
 handleClick: function(e){
  var name = e.target.name;
  if(name === 'decrease'){
   if(this.state.amount > 1){
    this.setState({
     amount : (this.state.amount  - 1)
    });
    AppActions.updateAmount(this.props.index, (this.state.amount  - 1))
   }
  }else{
   this.setState({
     amount : (this.state.amount + 1)
   });
   AppActions.updateAmount(this.props.index, (this.state.amount + 1))
  }
 },
 handleChange: function(e){
  var amount = e.target.value;
  this.setState({
   amount : amount
  });
  AppActions.updateAmount(this.props.index, amount)
 },
 render: function() {

  var config = this.state.config
  
  return (
   <div className="file-amount">
    <span className="file-amount-text"> {config.filelist_quantity}: {this.state.amount} {config.filelist_pieces}</span>
    <div className="file-amount-fields">
     <i className="file-amount-decrease icon" name="decrease" onClick={this.handleClick} /> 
      <input className="file-amount-input" type="number" value={this.state.amount} onChange={this.handleChange} />
     <i className="file-amount-increase icon" name="increase" onClick={this.handleClick} /> 
    </div>
   </div>
  );
 }
});

module.exports = FileAmount;
```

Comment: This code looks a little fishy. You seem to have `AppActions` which implies you have a Flux store, yet you still keep state in this component. One of the biggest benefits of Flux's unidirectional data flow is that there is a single source of truth when it comes to app state, so if you use the store then you could do without the component's own state.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I left a comment on the original post, but on second inspection, it looks quite possible that you pass down `props.amount` from a Flux Store. If that is the case you're creating an infinite loop.

`handleClick` increments `state.amount`, then after the AppAction is called, the Store updates the component with `props.amount`, then the `onChange` fires because it is tied to `state.amount` and then `onChange` changes `state.amount` and changes `props.amount` when it calls `AppActions.updateAmount`.

Every time `props` or `state` are updated, React will call the `render()` method. If there is any way that `props` or `state` get updated *while* the `render()` executes, then you are likely going to run into an infinite loop.

Comment: Ignoring context, this sounds like a perfectly reasonable explanation for 1000 click events :)

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps adding a e.preventDefault(); to your handleClick method will stop this loop from being started.

Comment: I ran into something like this due to bubbling of the click. Are there any parent elements that could also trigger the same function?

Answer (score 0):

I removed the added javascript for the browser-sync proxy settings. That somehow screwed around with my react.